# Recursive implementation of Greatest Common Divisor in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Can someone please help me I am new to programming?

I would like to write a recursive method to get the Greatest Common Divisor in python.

I have been given this:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x % y
    return abs(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a [iterative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method) implementation of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for finding the [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

You can convert into a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) method like so:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    return gcd(y, x % y) if y else abs(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 from fractions import gcd
 a = gcd(20,8)
print(a)
```

> 4

Or if you want to implement this by yourself:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    return (gcd(y, x % y) if y else abs(x))
```